# How can I leave a variable undeclared if a certain value is null?

Tags: c#

The code-line looks like this:

```
ActiveEndDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] != null ? 
DateTime.Parse(item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate].ToString()) : (DateTime?)null
```

How can I make sure that if `item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate]` is not `null` declare it else dont declare anything to the `ActiveEndDate` variable, not even `null`.

It has to be during a object initialization

This is the surrounding code that was requested:

```
      var result = new Xannounce
                {

                    MyX = (
                        from item in items.Cast<SPListItem>()
                        from ta in (item[FieldId.x] as string ?? "").Replace(";", string.Empty).Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        where audienceIds.Select(x => x.xID).Contains(ta)
                        select new Xannounce
                            {
                                Xid = item.ID,
                                Xpub = item[BuiltInFieldId.ResponsiblePublisher] as string ?? string.Empty,
                                XformUrl = item.ParentList.DefaultEditFormUrl,
                                ActiveEndDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] != null ? DateTime.Parse(item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate].ToString()) : (DateTime?)null,
                                ActiveStartDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveStartDate] != null ? DateTime.Parse(item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveStartDate].ToString()) : (DateTime?)null,
                                XEndDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.EndDate] != null ? DateTime.Parse(item[BuiltInFieldId.EndDate].ToString()) : (DateTime?)null,
                                XStartDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.StartDate] != null ? DateTime.Parse(item[BuiltInFieldId.StartDate].ToString()) : (DateTime?)null,
                                XTitle = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title].ToString(),
                                XMessage = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Body] != null ? item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Body].ToString() : string.Empty,
                                Xtype = new SPFieldLookupValue(item[BuiltInFieldId.AnnouncementType].ToString()).LookupId,
                                XAuthor = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].ToString(),
                                XAudienceNames = AudienceUtility.FindAudiences(item[FieldId.AudienceTargeting].ToString(), SPServiceContext.Current).Select(y => ' ' + y.AudienceName).ToArray()
                            }),
// Code continues...
```

Any kind of help or tips is appreciated alot

Comment: Well, you're assigning *something* to that variable (the result of the ternary conditional operator). Unfortunately, there is no "nothing, not even `null`" value that you could use in assignments.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Although if ActiveEndDate is a property with some side-effect in the setter, I could see the use case for avoiding assignment (even null)...

Comment: You have to assign anything to ActiveEndDate, otherwise at the moment you are trieing to acces it you will get an exception

Comment: @pamphlet yeah I just want to avoid the assignment

Comment: If the item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] is not null I want assign the variable else not

Comment: Is the value of BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate known at compile time? If it is you could use conditional compilation.

Comment: @Tomtom Actually, if nothing is ever assigned to the variable (and it's a possibility the compiler can detect) the compiler won't let the program *compile*.  It won't make it to a runtime exception.

Comment: Are you using a dynamic object? Can you post more of the surrounding code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign `ActiveEndDate` back to itself, which will have the same result as doing nothing as long as there are no weird side effects attached to your property. Also, reading through your code, you call .ToString() only to re-parse it. This seems like a bad idea. If the expression is already a datetime, use that. If it's not, don't call .ToString(). Presuming it is a DateTime, your existing code simplifies to this:

```
ActiveEndDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] ?? ActiveEndDate;
```

If it's something else, you can do this:

```
ActiveEndDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] != null ? DateTime.Parse(item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate].ToString()) : ActiveEndDate;
```

One final bit of syntax you might find useful is the `default` keyword:

```
ActiveEndDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] ?? default(DateTime);
```

Note that the default value for a DateTime expression (not DateTime?) is `1/1/1900`. The default value for a `DateTime?` is null.

One additional wrinkle I haven't covered yet is `DBNull`. If your `item` variable is an IDataRecord of some kind (SqlDataReader, DataRow, etc) you might be dealing with `DBNull`'s, which could throw kinks into my other options. This might also explain why you're calling .ToString() here, because .ToString() handles DBNull in a more sane way than some other options. It's great if you have a string type (like varchar) in the DB anyway, but when dealing with other types like dates and numbers it's still backwards for the (hopefully more common) case when you actually have a value.

In that event, I recommend a simple `if ()  {}` block to check first, as already posted in another answer. If you're doing object initialization (as suggested by a comment to another answer) things start to get complicated. Now we have a lot of logic that has to all fit into a single expression, to handle the case for `null`, `DBNull`, and a value. If that's your situation, I'd use this:

```
ActiveEndDate = (item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] == DBNull.Value?null:item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate]) ?? ActiveEndDate
```

Comment: @Rohander then you probably need to use if(){ } block, which may mean breaking out of an object initializer.

Answer (score 5):

How about not using the ternary operator?

```
if(item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] != null){
          ActiveEndDate =  item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate];
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's asking for something he can use during an object initialization.

Comment: It has to be during a object initialization

Comment: Boy, this got a lot of upvotes for not being close to an answer...  Lots of quick draw going on.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Well, accroding to the original user that's what he did

Answer (score 0):

Expand the ternary into an if statement:

```
if (item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate] != null) {
  ActiveEndDate = item[BuiltInFieldId.ActiveEndDate];
}
```

Pretty sure `ActiveEndDate` will default to DateTime.MinValue (`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`) anyway though.

Comment: It has to be during a object initialization

Comment: Depends on what ActiveEndDate is.  If it is a `DateTime` then it will be the min value.  If it is a `Nullable<DateTime>` (`DateTime?`) then it will be null.  If it is unassigned, it will be an exception.